# Array of uniformly spaced numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I wanted to create a grid of equally spaced numbers. So far I obtained this:

```
m = Table[{i, j}, {i, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5}, {j, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5}]
```

Now when I am trying to cast them as vectors I obtained:

```
{ {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 1.}},
  {{0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.5},{0.5, 1.}}, 
  {{1., 0.}, {1., 0.5}, {1., 1.}} }
```

Which, instead, I would like to be something like:

```
{{0., 0.}, 
 {0., 0.5}, 
 {0., 1.}, 
 {0.5, 0.}, 
 {0.5, 0.5},
 {0.5, 1.},
 ...., }
```

Comment: perhaps [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) is what you're looking for

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You simply wanna join your sublists: m =Join@@ Table[{i, j}, {i, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5}, {j, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5}]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert the full array into a list of pairs using [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html), [`Catenate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html), or [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html):

```
Join @@ m
Catenate[m]     (* version 10 or later *)
Flatten[m, 1]
```

(`@@` is shorthand for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html).  See also [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) and [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html).)

However there are arguably better ways to approach this problem from the outset than using [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).  Knowing that you want a "flat" output of pairs I would turn to [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html).  The uniformly spaced numbers can be generated with [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html), which is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), allowing this for your example:

```
Tuples @ Range[0, {1, 1}, .5]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 1.}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.5},
>  {0.5, 1.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 0.5}, {1., 1.}}
> ```

Generalized to ranges that do not share common values, in two equivalent forms

```
Tuples @ Range[{0, 7}, {1, 8}, {.5, 1}]

Tuples[{Range[0, 1, .5], Range[7, 8, 1]}]
```

> ```
> {{0., 7}, {0., 8}, {0.5, 7}, {0.5, 8}, {1., 7}, {1., 8}}
>
> {{0., 7}, {0., 8}, {0.5, 7}, {0.5, 8}, {1., 7}, {1., 8}}
> ```

If you did want a full array instead of a flat list of pairs then look at [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) and [`CoordinateBoundsArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundsArray.html):

```
Array[List, {3, 3}, {{0`, 1}}]

CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 0.5]
```

The syntax of `Array` is unlike the others in that the *number of steps* is specified rather than the *size* of the steps; this is sometimes more convenient.

Each of these generalized to the second example given for `Tuples`:

```
Array[List, {3, 2}, {{0`, 1}, {7, 8}}]

CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, 1}, {7, 8}}, {0.5, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{{0., 7}, {0., 8}}, {{0.5, 7}, {0.5, 8}}, {{1., 7}, {1., 8}}}
>
> {{{0., 7}, {0., 8}}, {{0.5, 7}, {0.5, 8}}, {{1., 7}, {1., 8}}}
> ```

---

Answer (score 4):

I'd use Outer, and then Flatten to get the desired level:

```
Flatten[Outer[List, Range[0, 1, 0.5], Range[0, 1, 0.5]], 1]

{{0., 0.}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 1.}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.5}, 
 {0.5, 1.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 0.5}, {1., 1.}}
```

Comment: Would you really? Why not `Tuples`?  I'm all for alternatives (i.e. thanks for posting this), but practically I find `Tuples` superior here.

Comment: You are probably right... but I always find `Outer` and `Inner` products to be concrete feeling, and I like that you can tell them which operations to use when combining. I guess when the operation is `List`, there are many other possibilities.

Comment: I can understand that perspective.  By the way to do you know that `Tuples` works on any head? `Tuples[foo[{a, b, c}, h[1, 2, 3]]]`

Comment: One man's Tuples is another man's Outer: `Flatten[Outer[foo, {a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}], 1] == Tuples[foo[{a, b, c}, h[1, 2, 3]]]` returns `True`. It's kind of amazing that `h` just disappears.

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155746/106) given by [bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s):

```
Range[0, 1, 0.5] // Distribute[{#, #}, List] &
```

```
% // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0. & 0. \\
 0. & 0.5 \\
 0. & 1. \\
 0.5 & 0. \\
 0.5 & 0.5 \\
 0.5 & 1. \\
 1. & 0. \\
 1. & 0.5 \\
 1. & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$